# Splitting one fields into several comments - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that have multiple comments in one field. 
For eg,

> 1) CLAIM REFILED Rebecca Byrd 1/17/2018 3:17:53 PM PER CHGS, WE NEED
>   TO REFILE THIS CLAIM Rebecca Byrd 1/10/2018 1:55:37 PM WAITING ON HOME
>   PLAN TO REPLY Rebecca Byrd 1/2/2018 1:58:31 PM A/R SENT TO CHGS ON
>   THIS CLAIM. DENIED AS A DUPLICATE, BUT THERE WAS ONLY ONE CLAIM IN
>   ILINKBLUE FOR THIS DOS. Test Byrd 12/29/2017 6:34:36 AM
>
> 2) HCRR ACCOUNT Sheila Johnson 9/28/2017 7:37:55 AM
>
> 3) Contacted VA VISN spoke with Mary she stated pmt $18.32 was made on
>   06/27/2014 -  #675678- she gave me treasury uh# 86-72-1141. I
>   contacted TEST and spoke with TEST - i gave her number, date and pmt -
>   she found ck and pmt of $0.00 for date 06/27/2014- she said it was
>   cashed under blah bank - trace #0jgdjgkd. Test Test 7/28/2017 1:21:11
>   PM

And I want to split it into different rows like this

```
1) CLAIM REFILED Rebecca Byrd 1/17/2018 3:17:53 PM 
2) PER BCBS, WE NEED TO REFILE THIS CLAIM Rebecca Byrd 1/10/2018 1:55:37 PM 
3) WAITING ON HOME PLAN TO REPLY Rebecca Byrd 1/2/2018 1:58:31 PM 
4) A/R SENT TO BCBS ON THIS CLAIM. DENIED AS A DUPLICATE, BUT THERE WAS ONLY ONE CLAIM IN ILINKBLUE FOR THIS DOS. Rebecca Byrd 12/29/2017 6:34:36 AM
```

All the comments will end with a date. So I will thinking I can use AM or PM as a separator. But Having difficulty separating it.

Comment: if your dbms is SQL server, then use string_split() function.

Comment: I did that but having little trouble splitting it. I am thinking about using AM or PM but I am not sure how do I use OR clause.

Comment: Let's see what you have so far. I'm sure someone here can help.

Comment: @AZ93 I'll try to give you a hint which you'll need to work on it, and if you need more help, you have to share what you have tried so far and tag your actual DBMS, edit your post so it can be more clearer to others, otherwise people will downvote it.

Comment: @AZ93 my hint will be using replace() with string_split (if is it SQL Server). use replace to add a period after PM or AM, then use string_split to split them by periods. adjust then any other strings, hint: `replace(string, ' PM ', ' PM.')` then `string_split(string,'.')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This design is very bad and you should - if there is any chance -
 really change this! Use this approach to transfer all comments into a related side table.

Your question is not very clear, but my magic crystal ball was in a good mood and telling me, that you might be looking for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitCommentOnTime(@str VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Pos
          ,LEFT(@str,PATINDEX('%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %',@str + ' ')+5) AS Part
          ,SUBSTRING(@str,PATINDEX('%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %',@str + ' ')+7,LEN(@str)) AS Remainder

    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pos+1
          ,LEFT(Remainder,PATINDEX('%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %',Remainder + ' ')+5) 
          ,SUBSTRING(Remainder,PATINDEX('%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %',Remainder + ' ')+7,LEN(@str)) 
    FROM recCTE
    WHERE PATINDEX('%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %',Remainder + ' ')>0
)
SELECT Pos,Part 
FROM recCTE;
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Comment VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('CLAIM REFILED Rebecca Byrd 1/17/2018 3:17:53 PM PER CHGS, WE NEED TO REFILE THIS CLAIM Rebecca Byrd 1/10/2018 1:55:37 PM WAITING ON HOME PLAN TO REPLY Rebecca Byrd 1/2/2018 1:58:31 PM A/R SENT TO CHGS ON THIS CLAIM. DENIED AS A DUPLICATE, BUT THERE WAS ONLY ONE CLAIM IN ILINKBLUE FOR THIS DOS. Test Byrd 12/29/2017 6:34:36 AM')
,('HCRR ACCOUNT Sheila Johnson 9/28/2017 7:37:55 AM')
,('Contacted VA VISN spoke with Mary she stated pmt $18.32 was made on 06/27/2014 - #675678- she gave me treasury uh# 86-72-1141. I contacted TEST and spoke with TEST - i gave her number, date and pmt - she found ck and pmt of $0.00 for date 06/27/2014- she said it was cashed under blah bank - trace #0jgdjgkd. Test Test 7/28/2017 1:21:11 PM')

SELECT *
FROM @tbl 
OUTER APPLY dbo.SplitCommentOnTime(Comment); 


GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.SplitCommentOnTime;
```

The result

```
ID  Pos Part
1   1   CLAIM REFILED Rebecca Byrd 1/17/2018 3:17:53 PM
1   2   PER CHGS, WE NEED TO REFILE THIS CLAIM Rebecca Byrd 1/10/2018 1:55:37 PM
1   3   WAITING ON HOME PLAN TO REPLY Rebecca Byrd 1/2/2018 1:58:31 PM
1   4   A/R SENT TO CHGS ON THIS CLAIM. DENIED AS A DUPLICATE, BUT THERE WAS ONLY ONE CLAIM IN ILINKBLUE FOR THIS DOS. Test Byrd 12/29/2017 6:34:36 AM
2   1   HCRR ACCOUNT Sheila Johnson 9/28/2017 7:37:55 AM
3   1   Contacted VA VISN spoke with Mary she stated pmt $18.32 was made on 06/27/2014 - #675678- she gave me treasury uh# 86-72-1141. I contacted TEST and spoke with TEST - i gave her number, date and pmt - she found ck and pmt of $0.00 for date 06/27/2014- she said it was cashed under blah bank - trace #0jgdjgkd. Test Test 7/28/2017 1:21:11 PM
```

### Some explanation

The function uses a recursive CTE jumping through your strings looking for a pattern. the pattern is `%:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M %`. That means: a double point, followed by one digit out of 0-5, then a digit 0-9, a blank, either A or P and then an M and a blank.

The rest is `LEFT` and `SUBSTRING`

### Hint

After having split these string monsters you might use `REVERT()` and search for the the third blank. Take this fragment, again reverted, and convert it to a real `DATETIME`. This way you'd get a side table with a good query performance.

You might get the commenter out of this the same way...